# Hive query records processed count

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, explain

I want to know how many records processed or % of records proccessed by a query to fetch result  in hive.

I tried describe formatted for query, but unable to do.

describe formatted (select * from sample)

Answer (score 1):

Use explain command:

```
explain extended select * from sample
```

But the number of rows in the plan is taken from statistics because query was not actually executed yet. The number of `processed` rows will become known only after execution.

See manual here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Explain

Counters in the log after command finished look like this:

```
Counters=FileSystemCounters.FILE_BYTES_READ:165364556525,
FileSystemCounters.FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN:398475913171,
FileSystemCounters.FILE_READ_OPS:0,
FileSystemCounters.FILE_LARGE_READ_OPS:0,
FileSystemCounters.FILE_WRITE_OPS:0,
FileSystemCounters.HDFS_BYTES_READ:2403609087417,
FileSystemCounters.HDFS_BYTES_WRITTEN:2401487507859,
FileSystemCounters.HDFS_READ_OPS:185667,
FileSystemCounters.HDFS_LARGE_READ_OPS:0 HIVE.RECORDS_IN:204428194,
HIVE.RECORDS_OUT_0:63070586,
HIVE.RECORDS_OUT_1_schema.table_name:39980068,
HIVE.RECORDS_OUT_INTERMEDIATE:126141195,
HIVE.SKEWJOINFOLLOWUPJOBS:0,
Shuffle Errors.BAD_ID:0,Shuffle
```

Comment: Thanks for reply,  can I get that count anywhere  in logs after query executions

Comment: @kiran  If you are doing select, it says: `Time taken: 0.302 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)` at the end. If you are inserting table, says `Loading data to table sample
Table sample stats: [numFiles=1, numRows=0, totalSize=0, rawDataSize=0]` Try to switch on statistics gathering: `set hive.stats.autogather=true;`

Comment: I am looking for total row  query processed to fetch that 1 row ,   
 In the below link i can see 2 different fields like 'MAP_INPUT_RECORD' and 'MAP_OUTPUT_RECORDS'. Here i guess above 1 refers --MAP_OUTPUT_RECORDS.  How can i get input records one


https://acadgild.com/blog/counters-in-mapreduce/

Comment: @kiran AFAIK Counters are present in the job execution log and it is possible to parse them. It is not possible to get access to counters from Hive.

Comment: @kiran Counters in the logs look like: 'Counters=FileSystemCounters.FILE_BYTES_READ:165364556525,FileSystemCounters.FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN:398475913171,FileSystemCounters.FILE_READ_OPS:0,FileSystemCounters.FILE_LARGE_READ_OPS:0,FileSystemCounters.FILE_WRITE_OPS:0,FileSystemCounters.HDFS_BYTES_READ:2403609087417,FileSystemCounters.HDFS_BYTES_WRITTEN:2401487507859,FileSystemCounters.HDFS_READ_OPS:185667,FileSystemCounters.HDFS_LARGE_READ_OPS:0'  and so on.

Comment: Thanks leftjoin, somewhat like this i am looking. Here the logs are referring is hive logs?